# Convert JSON array of objects which have one object each to a JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have an array of objects which has an object within each element and looks like this

```
[
  {
    "person": {
    "name": "John",          
    "isActive": true,
    "id": 1
   }
 },
 {
    "person": {
    "name": "Ted",          
    "isActive": true,
    "id": 2
   }
 }
]
```

I would like to convert it into this format which doesn't have the class name:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "IsActive": true,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "Name": "Ted",
    "IsActive": true,
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

The result will allow me to parse the information into a Kendo UI grid. The conversion is being done in a Typescript file.

Comment: I see the comment is on hold as it is too broad. By stackoverflow defination "... if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format". I can clearly see from the answers below that it was a lack of knowledge on my behalf on data.map.
I did get the answer I needed. I did a search before I asked the question but my search results didn't show map as I kept using the keyword "convert".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` and return an object with the required key

```js
let data = [{
    "person": {
      "name": "John",
      "isActive": true,
      "id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "person": {
      "name": "Ted",
      "isActive": true,
      "id": 2
    }
  }
];


let newData = data.map(function(item) {
  return {
    Name: item.person.name,
    IsActive: item.person.isActive,
    id: item.person.id
  };
});

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was able to map the old object to the newer object and realised that this also fixed the differences in variables name -> Name.  It also appeared successfully for me in the kendo UI grid

Comment: @Sniipe happy to help

Answer (score 2):

You could map the destructured property `person`.

```js
var data = [{ person: { name: "John", isActive: true, id: 1 } }, { person: { name: "Ted", isActive: true, id: 2 } }],
    result = data.map(({ person }) => person);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method

```js
const arr = [{"person": {"name": "John","isActive": true,"id": 1}},{"person": {"name": "Ted","isActive": true,"id": 2}}]
.map(({ person }) => {
  return {
    "Name": person.name,
    "IsActive": person.isActive,
    "id": person.id
  }
})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple 
    people.map(p=>p.person)

```js
var people=[
  {
    "person": {
    "name": "John",          
    "isActive": true,
    "id": 1
   }
 },
 {
    "person": {
    "name": "Ted",          
    "isActive": true,
    "id": 2
   }
 }
]

var newPeople=people.map(p=>p.person)

console.log(newPeople)
```